# XamlObjectWriterException: Collection property 'System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource'.'DesignSource' is null

Tags: c#, xaml

In VS2013, if we use the collectionView and set listbox's Itemsource BindDisplayingList, there is no xaml error. The xaml can be dipalyed correctly.
However, in VS2015, if we use the same project which work well in VS2013, there is xaml error saying that DesignSource is null. 
I just searched about the error but cannot find suitable answer about this.
The xaml code is as below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="brandViewModelViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:BrandViewModel}, CreateList=True}"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource  brandViewModelViewSource}" x:Name="MainContainer">
        <ListBox Margin="2,120,75,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="950" Background="White" x:Name="brandDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding BrandDisplayList}"   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Name="border" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="7"
          Padding="0" Margin="5,15,5,15">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="162"   >
                            <Grid Height="42"  Width="161">
                                <Label  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Arial"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  Content="{Binding BrandName}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Button Name="NavButton"  Width="161" Height="42" ClickMode="Press" Command="{Binding CmdDrillDown, Source={StaticResource brandViewModelViewSource}}" CommandParameter="{Binding BrandName}" Content="{Binding ProdCount}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Arial" >
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"  />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The related viewmodel is in BrandViewmodel.cs as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class BrandViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<BrandInfoViewModel> BrandDisplayList
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Get<ObservableCollection<BrandInfoViewModel>>("BrandDisplayList");
            }
            set
            {
                this.Set<ObservableCollection<BrandInfoViewModel>>("BrandDisplayList", value);
            }
        }

        private IDictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        protected T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            object v;
            if (values.TryGetValue(key, out v))
                return (T)v;

            return default(T);
        }

        protected T Get<T>(string key, Func<T> defaultaction)
        {
            var v = this.Get<T>(key);
            if (v == null)
            {
                v = defaultaction();
                this.Set<T>(key, v);
            }

            return v;
        }

        protected void Set<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            object v;
            values.TryGetValue(key, out v);
            if (v == null || !v.Equals(value))
            {
                this.values[key] = value;

                this.NotifyPropertyChanged(key);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        internal protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class BrandInfoViewModel
    {

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to avoid such error in VS2015?